# Jenkins CI: 'NumberFormatException: empty String'

Tags: jenkins, nunit

We have a Jenkins installation and some projects which are tested by NUnit. This works fine and it writes an NUnit results XML file.
Then we have a 'Publish NUnit test result report' post-build step. But since friday it produces this error:

```
Recording NUnit tests results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish NUnit test result report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx at hudson.remoting.Channel@205d5d5c:CIAgent: java.io.IOException: Failed to read C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx\temporary-junit-reports\TEST-xxx_Tests.TestsWithRealServers.TestWithTwoLocals_1_2.xml
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.plugins.nunit.NUnitPublisher.getTestResult(NUnitPublisher.java:226)
    [...]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx\temporary-junit-reports\TEST-xxx_Tests.TestsWithRealServers.TestWithTwoLocals_1_2.xml
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:306)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:244)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:175)
    [...]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    [...]
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

The XML file is present in the working directory. I mentioned that the first line of this file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="xxx_Tests.TestsWithRealServers.TestWithTwoLocals" skipped="6" tests="6" time="">
```

So I guess it fails because the time attribe is empty.

Does anyone how I can fix this or why this error occurs?
Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the result file actually produced by NUnit. What does that look like?

Comment: The NUnit results file: http://pastebin.com/HEZuUVWv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade the jenkins JUnit plugin to 1.12? There is a [reported issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34407) in this update. You might try downgrading back to 1.11.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer! I'll give it a try. But why should it be a problem with JUnit? I'm testing with NUnit... Does it depend on JUnit?

Comment: You may have noticed part of the path to your test results is "\temporary-junit-reports\". The NUnit jenkins plugin simply converts the NUnit output into something that the JUnit plugin can parse. When the NUnit plugin skips a test, it puts an empty string in the time section (I suspect you will see this if you look at TEST-xxx_Tests.TestsWithRealServers.TestWithTwoLocals_1_2.xml). The JUnit 1.12 plugin crashes trying to parse the empty time string. Downgrading to 1.11 fixed it for me. I expect to see 1.13 very soon.

Comment: Yes - it works! I just downgraded the JUnit plugin to 1.11. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Jenkins plugins does not support Nunit 3 XML format. I also had a similar problem on Jenkins. I used to convert Nunit 3 result format to Nunit 2 format.

```
"C:\NUnit 3.5.0\nunit3-console.exe" /result:\MyApplication.xml;format=nunit2 "D:\Jenkins\workspace\MyApplication.Tests.dll"
```